# TypeScript typing errors when piping/composing functions

Tags: typescript, eslint, ramda.js

When piping data that varies in type, I receive typing errors. How can I satisfy TypeScript?

```
const square = (x: number) => x * x

console.log(
  R.pipe(
    R.add, // two values
    square // one value
  )(1, 2)
)
```

> [tsserver 2769] [E] No overload matches this call.The last overload
> gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(x: number) => number' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(x: (b: number) => number) => number'.
>
> Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
>
> Type '(b: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.

I have `@types/ramda` installed.

Comment: Can you try `R.pipe(R.add, square)(1)(2)` and see if it helps?
e.g separate the 1 and the 2 to different pairs of parantheses

Comment: @YaronGrushka Currying the parameters produces:
[tsserver 2349] [E] This expression is not callable. Type 'Number' has no call signatures.
[tsserver 2554] [E] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unsatisfying solution, but it does work. I temporarily replaced `R.add` with a locally defined function of simpler type:

```
const add = (a: number, b: number) => a + b
const square = (x: number) => x * x

console.log(
  R.pipe(
    add, // two values
    square // one value
  )(1, 2)
)
```

Observing the instantiation of `R.pipe` in your original non-compiling example (`<number, number>`) vs. this simplified example (`<number, number, number, number>`), I realized that TypeScript was incorrectly choosing the curried overload of `R.add` and getting confused from there. If we explicitly instantiate `R.pipe` with the correct total arity, the compiler makes the right decision:

```
const square = (x: number) => x * x

console.log(
  R.pipe<number, number, number, number>(
    R.add, // two values
    square // one value
  )(1, 2)
)
```